# Flutter, how to make button link to another page

Tags: flutter

```
Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.green.shade100),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                  child: Row(
                  children: const [ Text("Pay Now",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                 ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                    size: 16,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )
                  ],
                )
                )
```

tried using gesture detector, `onPressed`. all could not work

Answer (score 0):

how about wrapping GestureDetector and onTap?

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    // onTap event here
  },
  child: Container() // your container
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using InkWell? The difference with GestureDetector is it has ripple effects but it detects less type of gestures from user.

```
InkWell(
    onTap: () {
       // go to another page
    },
    child: Container(...)
);
```